# duplicate entry error when using POI with gradle

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-poi, android-gradle-plugin

I started a project which needed the Apache POI library. I pasted them in my build.gradle file and everything seemed fine. Until I build the debug app.

I am getting the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':mobile:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class

I have tried removing and adding exclude group and module, but nothing has helped. When I do get the debug apk to build, and run the app, the app crashes because org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions is not found when opening a DOCX file. The DOC files work fine.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "{application_id}"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false

        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet false
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError true
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings false
        // turn off checking the given issue id's
        disable 'TypographyFractions', 'TypographyQuotes'
        // if true, generate a text report of issues (false by default)
        textReport true
        // location to write the output; can be a file or 'stdout'
        textOutput 'stdout'
        // if true, generate an HTML report (with issue explanations, sourcecode, etc)
        htmlReport true
        // optional path to report (default will be lint-results.html in the builddir)
        htmlOutput file("lint-report.html")
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.sis.storage.DataStoreProvider'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.detect.Detector'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.sis.internal.jaxb.TypeRegistration'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.parser.Parser'
        exclude 'META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt'
    }

}

repositories{

    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/raw/master/releases"}
    maven {url  "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"}
    maven {url  "http://dl.bintray.com/dasar/maven"}

}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jcl-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jcl-over-slf4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-simple'
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'

    compile ('org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.13'){
        exclude group: 'net.sf.log4jdbc'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j.logger'
    }

    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'de.jetwick:snacktory:1.1'

    compile 'com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3'

    // The material design file browser library
    compile 'com.nbsp:library:1.02'

    // Epub library
    compile 'nl.siegmann.epublib:epub-core:1.0@aar'


    // Begin for Office documents dependencies

    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'

    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi:3.13'){
        transitive = false
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
        exclude module: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }

    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.13'){
        transitive = false
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
        exclude module: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }

    compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.13'){
        transitive = false
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
        exclude module: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }

    compile ('org.apache.tika:tika-core:1.11'){
        transitive = false
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }
    compile ('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.11'){
        transitive = false
        exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
        exclude module: 'org.apache.xmlbeans'
    }
    // End for Office documents dependencies

    // PDF document library
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.8'



}
```

I have checked if there are any other dependencies using the org.apache.xmlbeans dependency, but I haven't found one.

If anybody would have a solution, please feel free to answer the question, but I would appreciate it if you tell us how you come to the answer.

Tim

EDIT:

When executing this command:

> gradlew -q dependencies mobile:dependencies --configuration compile

(output here: http://pastebin.com/7TugFR3J)
The org.apache.xmlbeans dependency is only listed once. Might there be a problem relating to any default java component?

EDIT NO.2:

I found that Java has a component like this: javax/xml/stream/Location.class
So I think I need to remove it from the build, but I don't know how.

Comment: I ran into this error two months ago, there are multiple classes in the library which have duplicate where android gives error, so I made JSON data in Java project and imported that in the Android code,

Comment: @PankajNimgade What do you mean by JSON data? Do you know how to exclude javax.xml.stream.Location from the gradle build?

Comment: i tried several methods but it didn't work and I had to read the excel file which had static values. so I created a java project in the Eclipse, imported the poi libraries and read the data from excel and saved everything by making a JSON data out of excel sheet. that's how i managed.

Comment: That isn't going to work for my problem, sadly enough.

Comment: yup you are right, i just had to read three spreadshets, so i managed it like that

Comment: I believe that there's a packaging error in the Apache XMLBeans 2.6 jar, which it looks like you're hitting

Comment: Do you suggest going back to a lower version of XMLBeans? Will is still be compatible with apache poi 3.13 @Gagravarr

Comment: If it matters to you, I'd suggest you just do your own custom patched version of the XMLBeans 2.6 jar without the duplicates in it. Any version from 2.3 onwards should be supported, but there are bug fixes in later versions you'd miss out on

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks! I'll try and patch it, any suggestions?

Comment: If you just unzip / unjar it, then re-jar it, that should remove the duplicates

Comment: @Gagravarr I can remove the org.apache.xml.stream.Location file when there are usages of it safely?

Comment: No, you need to keep it there. However, you only need the one copy. If you expand and re-package, it'll remove the duplicates

Comment: @Gagravarr Could you provide some guide or something? I am completely new to this phenomenon. I haven't found anything that was able to help me out with this issue

Comment: @tim687 did you find any solution yet? I am stuck with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

1. Unzip the `jar` file. (Simply change `.jar` extension to `.zip`
2. This will remove the duplicate files.
3. Recreate the `jar` using `jar cf xmlbeans.jar -C (path to unzipped folder) .` (Mind it, there is a dot in the end of command)
4. Use this regenerated `jar`

Comment: Could you take a look to this please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023667/xml-beans-2-6-exception-with-excel-creation-on-android