# Xml Beans 2.6 exception with Excel creation on Android

Tags: java, android, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to create `.xlsx` documents with the Apache POI 3.14 library.

This is my Gradle config:

```
(...)    
defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 19

            multiDexEnabled true

        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
                proguardFile 'Path/app/proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        //compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
        compile files('libs/poi-3.14-20160307.jar')
        compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar')
        compile files('libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar')
        compile files('libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/curvesapi-1.03.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
        compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
        compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
        compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.3.1'

    }
```

With the original xmlbeans library `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` I get this exception when I try to run APP

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class
```

I've tried to remove the duplicated class with this method

```
-Unzip the jar file. (Simply change .jar extension to .zip
-This will remove the duplicate files.
-Recreate the jar using jar cf xmlbeans.jar -C (path to unzipped folder) . (Mind it, there is a dot in the end of command)
-Use this regenerated jar
```

When I try to run the app with this recompiled .jar I get this warnings but even so it is launched to the device

```
    Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
    Error:(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.RussianDollStrategy$1) that doesn't come with an
    Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
    Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
    Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
    Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
    Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
    Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
(...)
```

Then when in my code try to do :

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

I get this exception and closes the app

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:41)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:162) 
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:142) 
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37) 
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:67) 
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.create(OPCPackage.java:344) 
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.newPackage(XSSFWorkbook.java:453) 
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:226) 
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218) 
 at com.asde.armatest.persistency.AsyncExcelFile.doInBackground(AsyncExcelFile.java:285)
```

What would be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POI : duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/BindigConfig.class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596776/poi-duplicate-entry-org-apache-xmlbeans-xml-stream-bindigconfig-class)

Comment: I 've already done all of sugested on this thread and the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this](https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX) repacked version. It is a bit limited but for my needs work good. It is for Android 4 and works on Android 5

Thanks